# Unable to incorporate stored procedure results into Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to incorporate a full-text search into Entity Framework Core.

I've given up trying to incorporate a full-text query directly. So I bit the bullet and added two stored procedures.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFullTextSearchResults]
    @SearchTerm     nvarchar(4000),
    @SkipRows       int,
    @TakeRows       int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT [Articles].[Id],
        [Articles].[Title],
        [Articles].[Slug],
        [Articles].[Description],
        [Categories].[Title] AS [Category],
        [Articles].[UserId],
        [AspNetUsers].[Name] AS [UserName],
        [Articles].[UtcDateModified]
    FROM [Articles]
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Articles], *, @SearchTerm) [t] ON [Articles].[Id] = [t].[Key]
    INNER JOIN [Subcategories] ON [Subcategories].[Id] = [Articles].[SubcategoryId]
    INNER JOIN [Categories] ON [Categories].[Id] = [Subcategories].[CategoryId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [AspNetUsers] ON [AspNetUsers].[Id] = [Articles].[UserId]
    WHERE [Articles].[Approved] = 1
    ORDER BY [t].[Rank] DESC
    OFFSET @SkipRows ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @TakeRows ROWS ONLY;
END");

    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFullTextSearchCount]
    @SearchTerm      nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM [Articles]
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Articles], *, @SearchTerm) [t] ON [Articles].[Id] = [t].[Key]
    WHERE [Articles].[Approved] = 1
END");
```

However, it looks like I still can't incorporate this because the columns returned match one of my view models, but not one of my entity models. I've read a limition of this is that Entity Framework Core can only retrieve entity types that are part of your model. (I need some related data, and downloading the entire entity model would include way too much data.)

I'm not sure why this turns out to be so complicated. But at this point, if I could just do an ADO.NET type of query, I'd settle for that.

So, how can I retrieve the results from `GetFullTextSearchResults`? Are there other options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003432/execute-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core-without-expecting-map-to-dbset/52003734#52003734, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975726/use-a-inline-table-valued-functions-with-linq-and-entity-framework-core/52976598#52976598, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076606/net-core-3-x-keyless-entity-types-avoid-table-creation/60079102#60079102

Answer (score 2):

You can create an entity type matching the returned columns.

Apply the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the entity class. Include a `DbSet` for the entity in your context. In the EF configuration set it to no key so EF never tries to update it, and don't assign any kind of table or view name.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityName>().HasNoKey();
```

You can retrieve the data with something like this:

```
var sessions = await _context.PersonSessionPaperRatingStatistics
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXECUTE YourStoredProcedureName {Parameter1},  {Parameter2}").ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for hours. The fact is, there is no simple way to run an ad-hoc query into an on-the-fly class.

So I wrote an extension method that provides this. The code simply accesses the `DbConnect` and uses a reader and reflection to read the results and populate the target type.

There are some limitations to this approach. For example, it ignores any transactions. But the goal is simple to return some data.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> SqlQuery<T>(this DbConnection connection, string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : new()
{
    // TODO: Do we need to close in this case?
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Open();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters);

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (!await reader.IsDBNullAsync(i))
                {
                    string name = reader.GetName(i);
                    PropertyInfo property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                    if (property != null && property.CanWrite)
                        property.SetValue(item, reader.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
            results.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```