# Entity Framework Core Code First trying to add stored procedure as table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Hello I have a stored procedure called `dbo.GetFolderDocumentsHierarchy` and it maps directly to the following class.

```
public class DocumentDto:IModel
{
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    [CanBeNull]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have added it to my Context like so.

```
builder.Query<DocumentDto>();
```

I might add that I call it like:

```
var dtos = await _context
                .Set<DocumentDto>()
                .FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetFolderDocumentsHierarchy @Skip, @Take, @UserId", sqlParameters)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Now on to my issue, every time I create a new migration it adds the following code to the migration and to the snapshot.

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "DocumentDto",
            columns: table => new
            {
                FolderId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                FolderName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                DocumentName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ParentName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ParentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
            });
```

And in the snapshot:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity("Models.Dtos.DocumentDto", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("DocumentName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<int>("FolderId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("FolderName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int?>("ParentId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("ParentName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.ToTable("DocumentDto");
            });
```

How can I make this not add to the migrations anymore?

**EDIT:**
Adding full context.

```
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GroupDocument> GroupDocuments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserDocument> UserDocuments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserFolder> UserFolders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserTask> UserTasks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Opportunity> Opportunities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<UserTask>()
            .HasIndex(x => x.OwnerId);

        builder.Entity<Group>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Campaigns)
            .WithOne(x => x.Group);
```

#pragma warning disable 618
builder.Query();
#pragma warning restore 618

```
        builder.Entity<GroupDocument>()
            .HasKey(gd => new { gd.GroupId, gd.DocumentId });
        builder.Entity<UserDocument>()
            .HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.DocumentId});
        builder.Entity<UserFolder>()
            .HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.FolderId});

    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't create a table unless you have declared a `DbSet<DocumentDto>` property on your context

Comment: I agree. But it does, I will post my full context if that is helpful.

Comment: It's recommended that you upgrade to EF core 3 at least. In that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079102/861716) would be a duplicate. In EF 5 you can't use `null` as argument for `ToView`.

Comment: I am using EF Core 3.1.8

Comment: Then you're ready to leave this obsolete method and move on to the code in the duplicate. Also, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).

Comment: I see the documentation, thank you for that, but it looks like its a view, will it work with a sproc too?

Comment: @GertArnold I was able to use the document with the view. If you add an answer I will give you the bounty.

Comment: I'll try later today when I've got time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main trick is mentioned in Ivan Stoev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079102/861716), which is to add a `ToView` mapping statement, always. Even when there is no view. The only difference is that EF core 5 doesn't support `.ToView(null)`, you have to enter some string.

In general, your options are:

**1**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentDto>
( eb => 
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToSqlQuery("EXEC StoredProcedureWithoutParameters");
        // Or: eb.ToSqlQuery("SELECT ... FROM ... ");
        eb.ToView("dummy view name"); // To prevent table creation.
    }
);
```

Or, when there *is* a view you map the DTO to:

**2**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentDto>
( eb => 
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToView("MyView"); // Map to existing view
    }
);
```

Or, just to map the DTO as keyless entity:

**3**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentDto>
( eb => 
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToView("Dummy view name"); // To prevent table creation
    }
);
```

When using option 3, you should populate the DTOs by code that you already have, something like:

```cs
context.Set<DocumentDto>()
       .FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetFolderDocumentsHierarchy @Skip, @Take, @UserId",
            sqlParameters)
```

This is the only way, to my knowledge, to use a stored procedure with parameters. Maybe there is some fancy way to use option 1 and make EF pass the predicates of a `Where` statement to the raw SQL query, but I doubt it.

I think the best option is to map the DTO to a real view (option 2, which you do now, as you mention in a comment), because in that case the `IQueryable` can be filtered by a `Where` statement. Also, it is composable in a way that generates one SQL statement, which allows the database engines query optimizer to calculate an overall query plan. Of course, this is only possible if the stored-procedure code can be transformed to a view.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from `Gert`, as stated in the actual solution on `GitHub`, was a workaround but it did its job.

Starting with EF Core 5.0, entity types are commonly mapped to tables or views such that EF Core will pull back the contents of the table or view when querying for that type. EF Core 5.0 adds additional mapping options, where an entity can be mapped to a SQL query (called a "defining query"), or to a table-valued function (TVF) - can be used also for `stored procedure` as well since it works quite similar to a `function`.

Also, you can exclude it from the migration even though you have defined a `DbSet<Dto>` for it.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().HasNoKey().ToFunction("[dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName]").Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);
```

And, I'd also use `FromSqlInterpolated` rather than `FromSqlRaw` to avoid SQL injection:

```
public async Task<List<Type>> GetListAsync(string externalUID)
    {
        try
        {
            var xList = await Context.DbSetType
                .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC [dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName] @externalUID = {externalUID}")
                .ToListAsync();

            return xList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.Message}");
            return new List<Type>();
        }
}
```